# Snake Game correct position for the tail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Someone can explain me how can i do to spawn the new tail parts near the head of the snake because the new parts appears on 0/0

```
var makeAStep = function() {
if (snake.detectCollision(snake.velocity) === true) {
    alert("You Loose, what a pity!");
    clearInterval(intervalHandler);
    return;
}

var lastItemPosition = snake.body[snake.body.length - 1].position.copy();

snake.move();

if (snake.getHead().isOnPosition(food.position)) {
    food.updateScore();
    generateFood();
    snake.body.push(new snakeItem(lastItemPosition));
}

snake.screenUpdate();
```

[fiddle with all the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/gZAeE/)

i think that i have to edit something here:

```
screenUpdate: function() {
    var offset = 0;
    var currentNode = null;
    for (i in this.body) {
        offset = 3 + parseInt(i);
        currentNode = $('#box :nth-child(' + offset + ')');

        if (currentNode.size() == 0)
            $('#box').append($('<div class="snakeItem"></div>'));

        currentNode.animate({top: $('#head').height() * this.body[i].position.y + "px"}, duration / 3);
        currentNode.animate({left: $('#head').width() * this.body[i].position.x + "px"}, duration / 3);
    }
```

Comment: too OOP for js) and for snake especially)

Comment: Your fiddle seems fine to me, except that new items are created at 0,0 and quickly moved to the end of the snake's tail. Is this the problem? You wanted to see the item on the tail immediately?

Comment: yes i want to show on the tail immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `.animate()` functions you use in `snake.screenUpdate()`. If you change them to `.css()`, for example, you'll see the new items directly in place. This, of course, would ruin the smooth movement of the rest of the snake, so you might want to treat items differently, like:

```
for (i in this.body) {
    offset = 3 + parseInt(i);
    currentNode = $('#box :nth-child(' + offset + ')');

    if (currentNode.size() == 0) {
        $('#box').append($('<div class="snakeItem"></div>'));
        currentNode = $('#box :nth-child(' + offset + ')');
        currentNode.css({top: $('#head').height() * this.body[i].position.y + "px"}, duration / 3);
        currentNode.css({left: $('#head').width() * this.body[i].position.x + "px"}, duration / 3);
    } else {
        currentNode.animate({top: $('#head').height() * this.body[i].position.y + "px"}, duration / 3);
        currentNode.animate({left: $('#head').width() * this.body[i].position.x + "px"}, duration / 3);
    }
}
```

This should work, if I understood your fiddle correctly.

Comment: In the init you have offset 2 and in the animation offset 3, that cuases the jump from 0,0 at the init (this answer fixes all jumps when eating the food).

Comment: Right, didn't notice that.

Comment: And what should i put there Raul?

Comment: Just use 3 + parseInt(i) in both cases and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#box').append($('<div class="snakeItem"></div>'));

Replace above code with following code.

var element = $('#box').find(".snakeItem").last();
var elementtop= $(testelement).css( "top");
var elementleft= $(testelement).css( "left");

$("<div>", {
'class': "snakeItem",
css: {
    "top": elementtop,
    "left":elementleft
}
}).appendTo($('#box'));
```